# django-registration 3.0.1 activation_email_body

Tags: django-registration

I'm new to django.

I have installed `django-registration` in version 3.0.1.
Can anyone help to write a link the user can click to activate the account for the `activation_email_body.txt` template.

The documentation on this provides no information. 
Here the [link to documentation](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.1/quickstart.html)

Please help

Answer (score 0):

This code generates link to activate new user:

```
{{ scheme }}://{{ site }}{% url 'django_registration_activate' activation_key=activation_key %}
```

I am not sure if it should be in a tag or not I have to test it, because in documentation is written that it sends plain text email.